# angularJs ng-grid shows blank grid first

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, paging, ng-grid

I have a complex form with several tabs. One tab has ngGrid on it and I am trying to apply pagination. My code is very similar to what we have on the ng-grid sample page except that it's a bit simpler:

```
  $scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, searchText) {
              //setTimeout(function ()
              {
                  var data;
                  if ($scope.currentAccount) {
                      //var acctNameHash = $scope.currentAccount.acctNameHash;
                      //var showFinalized = $scope.showFinalized;
                      var largeLoad = $scope.currentAccount.invoices;
                      if (searchText) {
                          var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
                          //$http.get('/api/accounts/getAccountInvoices/' + acctNameHash + '/' + showFinalized)
                          //    .success(function (largeLoad) 
                          {
                              data = largeLoad.filter(function (item) {
                                  return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(ft) != -1;
                              });
                              // Always use first page after applying a filter
                              $scope.setPagingData(data, 1, pageSize);
                          };
                      } else {
                          //$http.get('/api/accounts/getAccountInvoices/' + acctNameHash + '/' + showFinalized)
                          //    .success(function (largeLoad)
                          {
                              $scope.setPagingData(largeLoad, page, pageSize);
                          }
                          //);
                      }
                  }
              }
              //, 100);
          };
```

So, I load my data right away and when I don't re-load them.

My load method has this code:

```
accountsService.getAccount(id, isNew, $scope.showFinalized).then(function (data) {
              $scope.currentAccount = data;

              $scope.isNew = isNew;
              if (!isNew) {
                  $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);                 
              }
```

What I observe - the grid loads empty but shows correct number of items in the total items in the footer. As soon as I activate the Developer Tools (or deactivate them if they were already opened), the grid starts showing data properly and also correctly navigates and filters. So, some sort of initial "refresh" is missing, but I don't know how to do it.

Do you see what may be wrong or how can I do this "refresh" in code?

I commented out the code in the (!isNew) if of initial setting pages. It seems to help a bit but I seem to still have wrong behavior. Also, the grid itself looks awful in IE 11. While in Chrome I can see all columns, in IE I only see 2+ part of the 3rd column and the paging controls are in the wrong place.

Comment: I had a (nearly) similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157824/ui-boostrap-accordion-container-width-issue/24160257#24160257 This was related to accordion, but maybe you can simply try to resize the window and tell me what has happened. Just guessing ...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment till now. It may be indeed the reason. In my case we use tabs with this code <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 panel-container">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#general" ng-class="{true: 'invalid-tab', false: ''}[form.editAccountGeneral.$invalid]">General</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
etc. We also use special resize container class. I'll see if I can figure out how to invoke resize in our case.

Comment: Wow, how can I mark your comment as an answer? It works!!!!!!!!!! After I spent several days on this problem all I added was $(window).trigger('resize'); at the end of my load procedure and the grid now behaves. I think I'll try to re-introduce paging back which I removed in desperation. Thanks a lot again for answering.

Comment: I think it would be enough if you just upvote the given answer in the link. A higher vote will attract more users in search of help to this answer. Glad I could help you.

Comment: Yes, I certainly did this. Thanks again. Do you think it's a bug in ng-grid and should be posted as an issue?

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. But I'm not sure if it's in ng-grid or in ui-bootstrap. Since 3.x there is a completely new version of ng-grid (now: ui-grid) so I wouldn't post this issue anymore.