# UI-Grid, built with Angular and Bootstrap-UI will not size itself until window is sized in some way

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-grid

The first part here is the display of the grid in a section and form. They are able to export this grid to Excel or Crystal Reports. I've included the gridOptions that help build the grid and the columnDefs that are a big part of the gridOptions. There is a definition for every column and I've used the max data in each column to decide the size of the column. This dictates the size of the whole grid, but the container still fits into the viewable area. There is a horizontal scroll. The only problem I have is that this is only activated when the window is resized. Maximize, minimize, resize, change in any way and the grid will fit like it is supposed to perfectly. Otherwise the container does not stop in the viewable area like it is supposed to, it extends all the way around the width of the grid.

[image: Fits after window resize]

Has anyone run into anything like this anymore? I'd be happy if I just have to run something through $interval with 0 if that's what it takes, but this is very buggy behavior. This is a good amount of code, but the angular, bootstrap, and bootstrap ui is recent and standard. UI-Grid is RC20 (ui-grid - v3.0.0-rc.20-746a476 - 2015-03-19). Let know if you have any questions or if there is any more info I can provide. I suppose I could artificially shoot off a resize event from window and that could suffice, at the same time I get rid of the spinner.

[image: Doesn't fit on load unless window sized in someway, which triggers something]

```html
<section id="gridTemplate" ng-controller="gridCtrl">
    <h1 class="g-report-title">{{pageInfo.title}}</h1>
    <form role="form">
        <grid class="masked grid" id="grid1" spinner-key="spinnerGrid" spinner-start-active="true" ui-grid="gridOptions" external-scopes="$scope">
        </grid>
        <fieldset class="buttons" ng-controller="reportController">
            <button ng-hide="bPrint" class="btn btn-small btn-default" ng-click="printReport()">Report</button>
            <button ng-hide="bExport" class="btn btn-small btn-default" ng-click="exportData()">Export</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</section>
```

gridOptions mostly ends up like this:

```js
 $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableSorting: true,
        showHeader: true,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        multiSelect: true,
        data: $scope.data,
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        // needs more review and may only be applicable to editable grids
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
            gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
                var msg = 'row selected ' + row.isSelected;
                alert(msg);
            });
            ...
        }
    };
```

and there is a lot more to it than this, but columnDefs mostly ends up like this to get some size estimates based on content:

```js
for (var col in finalRow) {
    var def     = {};
    def.field   = col;
    var label   = col.replace('_', ' ');
    label       = label[0].toUpperCase() + label.substr(1, label.length);
    def.title   = label;
    def.visible = true;

    switch ($rootScope.pageInfo.reportName) {
        case 'CSOpenClaimsCache':
        case 'OpenClaimsOlderThanDate':
            if (col === 'Status' || col === 'CloseDate' || col === 'Resp' || col==='DSMNameAssigned' || col==='DSMName') {
                def.visible = false;
            }
        break;
    }
    def.width = maxColumnWidth[col];
    columnDefs.push(def);
}
```

The solution as aided by @mainguy

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
$scope.stopSpin('spinnerGrid');
```

The function def for stopSpin()

```
/*
 * stopSpin - static function wrapper to attach to $scope of high
 * lvl controller
 * $param string      key   Spinner key to stop
 * $param boolean  keep Keep the spinner, just hide it
 * $return void
 */
$scope.stopSpin = function (key, keep) {
  //better have injected this. It's very configurable, globally and individually
  usSpinnerService.stop(key, keep);
}
```

Comment: This Answer may be usefull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157824/ui-boostrap-accordion-container-width-issue/24160257#24160257

Comment: I'm going to add the window trigger resize hack. If it works, good enough for me for now.

Comment: The resize hack worked. In my grid controller that defines the grid options and sets up some column widths and other options, I added a line of code right before I shut off the "loading" spinner to indicate completion. I map $ to angular.element. stopSpin fn is defined in the next comment.

Comment: Good! Too bad that I can't mark your answer as solved. You get an upvote anyhow, so more seekers will be able to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution as aided by @mainguy. I stuck this in the controller that generates and places my grid. Right before I turn off the spinner, ie it's loaded, I send the resize event. Seems to work like a charm. I will report back if I notice any issues.

```
//$ is mapped to angular.element in my constants file
$(window).trigger('resize');
$scope.stopSpin('spinnerGrid');
```

The function def for stopSpin()

```
/*
 * stopSpin - static function wrapper to attach to $scope of high
 * lvl controller
 * $param string     key   Spinner key to stop
 * $param boolean    keep  Keep the spinner, just hide it
 * $return void
 */
$scope.stopSpin = function (key, keep) {
  //better have injected this. It's very configurable, globally and individually
  usSpinnerService.stop(key, keep);
}
```