# resize ng-grid when window size changed with click event

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am using ng-grid when I drag the window the grid resize well. But when I click a button to make the window bigger,the grid does not resize.

UPDATE: Actually, the grid is resized. However, the row and column are not.
I notice in 3.x they have autoresize function. Unfortunately, I cannot update to 3.x version. Is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: may be some responsive css ?? how about bootstrap ??

Comment: Maybe my answer here will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157824/ui-boostrap-accordion-container-width-issue/24160257#24160257

Comment: @mainguy Hi, thank you for you suggestion, but in my case the window and the grid is actually resized. However the row/column are stay the same(not resized).

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Hi, thank you for your replying. I think css might not help me in this case but I will try. Thanks again.

Comment: How about a basic Plunker that show us the issue in more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.gridOptions.$gridServices.DomUtilityService.RebuildGrid(
            $scope.gridOptions.$gridScope, 
            $scope.gridOptions.ngGrid
);
```

I used this code the rebuild the grid and it solve my problem.

Thanks for everyone's replay.